# Generic object instanciation

Tags: c++

I have a class:

```
    class User {
    public:
        int id = 0;
        std::string email = "";

        User(int id_, std::string email_) :
        id(id_), email(email_) {}

    };
```

I can contruct an instance like this:

```
    auto x=Model::User({3,"m"});
```

But i need to construct the instance using using data from a vector. I get this data from a DB and would like to make the construction of the object generic :

```
    auto v=std::vector<std::any>({3,"m"}); // from the db
    auto x=Model::User(v); // instanciate the object with a vector, does not work without special constructor.
```

Without modifying the class constructor. Is it possible to use parameter pack or initializer_list to do that?

Something like

```
template<typename T>
T makeobject(vector<any> args) {
    // instanciate new object of type T, initialised with data from args
    // and return it
}

auto u=makeobject<User>(v);
```

Comment: Normal instantiation can be shortened to `Model::User x{3,"m"};`. Use of vector or initializer list implies that your class is supposed to be constructed with arbitrary amount of items. But it accepts only two arguments.

Comment: `std::any` is error prone, `std::any_cast<std::string>(std::any("m"))` would fail. `std::variant` seems more appropriate, as type from Db should be limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do:

```
User makeUser(const std::vector<std::any>& args) {
    return User(std::any_cast<int>(args[0]), std::any_cast<const char*>(args[1]));
}
```

As C++ doesn't have reflection, to make it generic, you will have to provide traits to each class you want to support (or be compatible with [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get))

```
template <typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
T makeObject(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const std::vector<std::any>& args) {
    return T(std::any_cast<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>>(args[Is])...);
}

template <typename T>
T makeObject(const std::vector<std::any>& args) {
    using Tuple = typename T::TupleConstructor;
    return makeObject<T, Tuple>(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>(), args);
}
```

With

```
class User {
public:
    using TupleConstructor = std::tuple<int, const char*>;

    int id = 0;
    std::string email = "";

    User(int id_, std::string email_) :
    id(id_), email(email_) {}
};
```

external type_traits can be used instead of adding directly alias type in `User`.